# Progress towards a Polynomial time factoring algorithm?

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomials, factoring

This is probably insignificant, but I was messing around with polynomials, and found out that, if we have a number, n = pq that we want to factor, if we expand (k+1)^n -k^n - 1, mod n, the first nonzero term will be a factor of n. This, of course, is just trial division in disguise, since in order to find p, you would have to expand out at least p terms of the polynomial, or the entire thing. And, there are other numbers that pop up in this polynomial, all of which share common factors with n, and this is somewhat trivial to prove. However, if we set k = 1, we just get the sum of all these numbers that are coefficients, mod n.You could do this enough times at different points, and set up a mod n system of linear equations, but that would, again, take exponential time.You might be able to do some witchcraft with DFTs to get around this, but I don't understand the topic nearly well enough to wrap my head around this. But is this a productive avenue that has been explored before? I know that the AKS test uses a similar method for primality testing, could this be a potential factoring algorithm? As if there is some way to "cancel out" all the numbers in the polynomial that have factors other then p or q, you could just evaluate the polynomial at 1, and get ap+bq mod n,for some integer a and b and from their you could probably recover the factors after some more shenanigans with other fields. Or, perhaps because all the individual numbers share common factors with we could do something with that? I heard from another thread that if you can extract a bit of information about factors, you will probably be able to find them by doing stuff in other fields. Is there the potential to give enough information about the factors here? Could we find some of the nonzero coefficients of the polynomial by evaluating less then n points?  I'm not going to get my hopes up over this, but I just want to know if this will lead to anything interesting. I am just a senior in high school and don't have the most advanced math background. This probably won't lead to factoring being in P, but it will lead to me learning more about polynomials.

Comment: "ap+bq mod n,for some integer a and b and from their you could probably recover the factors after some more shenanigans with other fields." Every number mod n can be represented as ap+bq, so it doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @Command Master, if you could figure out what a and b are from the polynomial though.